# Complexity of simple undirected graph isomorphism problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, graph-isomorphism, gr.group-theory

We define a simple undirected graph as a graph where no vertex has a loop and there is only zero or one undirected, unweighted edge between any pair of vertices.

My question:

1. What is the complexity of the best known algorithm for the simple undirected graph isomorphism problem?

I assume it should be a special case of the exponential algorithm by Babai et. al introduced in [Canonical labeling of graphs](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=808746).

As described in [Reading List: Graph Isomorphism](http://dabacon.org/pontiff/?p=4148) by Dave Bacon, this is not among the classes for which we have efficient algorithms. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: I thought simple undirected graphs were the standard setting for graph isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

László Babai. [Graph Isomorphism in Quasipolynomial Time](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03547v1), 84 pages.  [Version 1.  Fri, 11 Dec 2015]

From [Abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03547v1) :

> We show that the Graph Isomorphism (GI) problem and the related problems of String Isomorphism (under group action) (SI) and Coset Intersection (CI) can be solved in quasipolynomial  $\exp ((\log n) ^ {O(1)}) $ time.

The best previous bound for GI was
$ \exp ( O ( \sqrt {n\log n} ) ) ,$
where $n$ is the number of vertices (Luks, 1983); for the other two problems, the bound was similar,
$ \exp ( \tilde O ( \sqrt n ) ) ,$
where n is the size of the permutation domain (Babai, 1983)

Comment: [Babai retracted the claim of quasipolynomial runtime](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/update.html). Apparently there was an error in the analysis.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the best known algorithm is still the algorithm from Babai and Luks, with runtime $\exp(O(\sqrt{n \log n}))$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graphs. Unless I'm mistaken, even the best known *conondeterministic* algorithm for graph isomorphism has exponential runtime. Babai and Luks' algorithm is plausibly near-optimal for deterministic algorithms, but there is much evidence that there is a polynomial time conondeterministic algorithm for graph isomorphism out there to be discovered. In particular, it is [known](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f11/lecture17.pdf) that graph isomorphism is in coAM, and certain circuit lower bounds [imply](http://www.brics.dk/RS/99/47/BRICS-RS-99-47.pdf) that coAM = coNP.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, "even the best known" bound on the [quantum Merlin-Arthur](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#qma) $\hspace{.75 in}$ complexity of graph non-isomorphism is exponential. $\;$